# How to generate new upload button in real time

Tags: forms, button, upload, real-time

I have a simple contact form with a file upload option built in. However, it only has 1 "Browse" button, and I want there to be unlimited. But instead of duplicating the "Browse" code a bunch of times, I'd rather it create a NEW browse button once the user has used the old one (uploaded a file).

How do I create another button in real-time?

Here is a full demo of the form: http://www.html-form-guide.com/files/contact-form/contact-form-attachment-1/contactform.php

The form's code is below, my question relates to upload button. Thank you!!

```
<form id='contactus' action='<?php echo $formproc->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset='UTF-8'>

<fieldset >
<legend>Describe the issue:</legend>

<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputName(); ?>' value='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputValue(); ?>'/>
<input type='text'  class='spmhidip' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetSpamTrapInputName(); ?>' />

<div class='short_explanation'>*All fields are required.</div>

<div><span class='error'><?php echo $formproc->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='name' >Full Name: </label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='name' id='name' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('name') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_name_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='email' >Email Address:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('email') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_email_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='message' >Message:</label><br/>
    <span id='contactus_message_errorloc' class='error'></span>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='message' id='message'><?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('message') ?></textarea>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='photo' >Upload your file:</label><br/>
    <input type="file" name='photo' id='photo' /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_photo_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>


<div class='container'>
    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you talking about dynamic button?

Comment: To get useful answers, remove some code and show only necessary part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have one upload button in html like this:

```
 <body>
    <form>
      <input type="file" name="upload1" id="upload1"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Then, you can add another upload button on `Click` event on previous button using `jquery`:

```
$(function(){
    $('#upload1').on('click',function(){
        var r= $('<input type="file" value="new button"/>');
        $("form").append(r);
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/krupal/SP8de/33/)

If you are not familiar with how to use `Jquery`, This is the place where you can learn:[Learn jquery](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Flearn.jquery.com%2F&ei=4AfjU6b1GoLl8AXNsoGwCw&usg=AFQjCNFU2xBSP687b-qZxfh70YaetZKxcA&sig2=Z4N1HR7luZ39KxzQvrntDw&bvm=bv.72676100,d.dGc)